# Deleting all shortcuts in Visual Studio 2016

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, keyboard, shortcut

My problem is that I'm using a hungarian keyboard which has got quite a lot of characters that can only be accesed with ctrl+alt+... combination(eg.{, [ ). I tried to remove some of the shortcuts manually but spite the fact I thought I deleted all,  I still can't use some of the key combinations without activating a shortcut.

Now, this problem is much more than an annoying little thing, I literally can't write a single line of code. So I want to get rid of all the shortcuts or at least delete those that contain ctrl+alt keys.

Comment: You are supposed to press the AltGr key to access to characters.  If you don't have one for some reason then spending $8.99 at amazon.com would be wise.

Answer (score 0):

You have english keyboard on your pc? Maybe this is the problem. If not, [look at this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258824).

If you want to change/delete shorcuts from Visual Studio, [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/5zwses53.aspx).

Also you can take a look [at this thread about ctrl + shift](https://superuser.com/questions/109066/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-for-the-same-input-language-i), it may help you perhaps. ( and [Configuring language settings](http://Configuring%20language%20settings%20in%20Windows%208) also )

Comment: Thanks for the help. Switching the registers of the left and right altgr so that I can use the left one solved the problem.